# Benefits of studying Banach algebras?

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, big-list, banach-algebras

I am busy studying Banach algebras and really enjoy the theorems and results that I have worked through so far.

This got me wondering - what significance has the study of Banach algebras brought to other topics within Mathematics, i.e. interesting results, significant simplification of proofs etc?

Can anyone please tell me a few of these results (and perhaps give a possible reference), as I would really like to read into them further. I have heard that Banach algebras have specific beautiful applications in the theory of Fourier Analysis, but what results within the field did it bring to surface?

Comment: It's the formal setting for understanding properties and spectra of operators on a Hilbert space, and therefore for understanding results about differential equations.

Comment: Do you know Wiener's 1/f theorem?

Comment: I read somewhere that the theory of abstract algebra, in particular Banach, is very useful to easy proofs and non-constructive proofs of many theorems of analysis.

Comment: It is actually the first example of how the theory applies to other fields of study. The concept of Banach algebras actually became well known when in 1940 I. Gelfand started studying them. Back then there was a hard (hard proof) theorem of Wiener that stated that if $f$ has an absolutely convergent Fourier series then 1/$f$ has it too. It turns out that the family of functiond with abs conv fourier series has a natural structure of banach algebra and from this setting the 1/f theorem becomes almost trivial (it can be proven in a few lines).

Comment: This is only the first example. There was a lot of them after that. If you can give to your particular space of study a banach algebra structure then youre combining a normed structure with a algebraical one, and so if you're concerned with properties related with this analitical-algebraic structure then you will probably find the easiest proof in this context. Not to mention the amount of interesting problems this theory brought, the Corona Theorem being the first gem of these....

Comment: Literally any algebraic thing that can be said about Banach algebras can also be said about finite-dimensional $\mathbb{C}$-algebras. So you get results like Gelfand-Mazur's theorem on division algebras, which is an improvement of a classical theorem of Frobenius, arrived at by completely different methods. See for example http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1874995/can-every-finite-dimensional-associative-mathbbc-algebra-be-equipped-with-a.